# How to enable seekable mp3 web service hosted by owin?

Tags: c#, owin

I'm writing a selfhosted web api using owin that serve mp3 files in my window pc to my android device. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/).

I'm able to host the service and my android device able to play the file from the web service. However i'm not allowed to seek the mp3 after the song played. The song just play from beginning to end. I'm using MX player to play the song from my android device.

Need some help here. Been searching using google for hours now but still not found a solution.